# What is the difference between these two method calls in c#?

Tags: c#, class, methods, console-application

For example I have some class with one `void` method in it.

This is my class:

```
class MyClassTest
{
    public void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello");
    }
}
```

I am new to classes and little confused, is there a difference between these two method calls?

Here is my main method

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //first call
    MyClassTest ms = new MyClassTest();
    ms.Print();

    //second call
    new MyClassTest().Print();
}
```

Comment: In short, no difference.

Comment: @JohnyL which way should i use more?

Comment: @RonJeremy say you want to call multiple methods of the same instance..will the second call still be an option? It is all about reusing the same instance.

Comment: It depends on whether you need the reference to `MyClassTest` class or not. If it's used as fire-and-forget, then it's better to make `Print` method as `static`.

Comment: @PeterBons thank you peter, I can duplicate also `new MyClassTest().Print();` when I want to call more methods, will that be an option?

Comment: *will that be an option?* I answered you earlier...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the case below you'll want to do this when you want to keep a reference to the constructed object and perform some further operations with it later on.

```
MyClassTest ms = new MyClassTest();
ms.Print();
```

Whereas, in the case below you'll *only* want to do this when you no longer care about the constructed object after construction but are just interested in calling the method `Print`.

```
new MyClassTest().Print();
```

The subtle difference between these two scenarios is that in the case where 
the object being referenced performs further operations it will most likely get destroyed later than an object that is no longer referenced i.e. the second example above as the GC (Garbage Collector) will find out that it has no references and therefore decides to get rid of it.

Comment: I'd go further to comment that if you find yourself doing the second often, you're more than likely doing something wrong. Use static methods if you don't care about the insances

Comment: In both cases object can be collected right after call to print (except if you run under debugger, where variable might live longer so that you can inspect its value).

Comment: @Evk Alright but generally objects that still have references are _most likely_ to be garbage collected later than the ones without and also the time at which objects are garbage collected is _non-deterministic_.

Comment: But after Print call both objects have no references any more (`ms` variable is not used anywhere below), so they both can be collected after this call (by can I mean that "can at any time after Print call", not exactly after Print call). So their lifetime is exactly the same.

Comment: @Evk I absolutely agree with you and also hence I mentioned _most likely_ within my post but I'll edit it to better clarify. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There's no difference, actually. You use the first case when you need to refer to `MyTestClass` further in your program. You use second case as `fire-and-forget`. If you plan using second case heavily, it's recommended to make `Print` method as `static`.

The IL code shows no difference, except WithInstance method when variable holding reference is loaded onto stack (`stloc.0` and `ldloc.0` IL instructions):

```
MyClassTest ms = new MyClassTest();
ms.Print();
```

[image: Image1]

```
new MyClassTest().Print();
```

[image: Image2]

Comment: Does second or static call of this method contribute to less space in memory because there is no variable holding reference ?

Comment: The second method allocates memory as well as first. As for static method, you should use either static class or regular class with static method.

Answer (score 0):

Your two calls perform the same semantic operation in c#: the difference is that in your first call, you create the `ms` variable, which suggests the reader that your intent is to use it again in your code: in fact you are calling `ms.Print()` after.

Your second call, does not declare any variable, this means that your intent is exactly to call the `Print` method on a brand new `MyClassTest` instance only once in your code, and you don't care about the instance your just created.

Side note: when compiling in release mode, the C# compiler will compact and reduce variable usage, therefore your two calls will compile the same and they will be like your second call.

Comment: thank you for nice explanation, about that release mode, will  using `ms` variable(obj) for some more properties make things different?

Comment: You are welcome. Using `ms` for additional "things" changes the compiled code. However, the exact output depends on many factors which are difficicult to estimate in the current context.

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case, no.

Any time you call a method on a result of another method call, `new`, property access, etc. as per:

```
new MyClassTest().Print();
```

It's akin to if you did:

```
var temp = new MyClassTest()
temp.Print();
```

So in this case your two examples are the same.

There are some variants where they differ.

One would be value-type objects that are accessed from array or field access. Here the access might use the address of the actual object rather than making a copy. Now it's possible for the opposite to happen where instead of an implicit temporary local being created and explicit local is removed, but it's not promised. Note that with mutable value-types the code with and without a temporary local are also not semantically the same for these cases (but are for a case closer to your example, where the object is the result of a method call that wasn't a `ref return` to a `ref` variable).

Another is when it is inside a `yield`-using or `async` method. Here the locals in your method become fields in an object produced (which either implements the `IEnumerable<T>` and/or `IEnumerator<T>` for `yield` or the `Task` for `async`) while the "invisible" temporary locals I described above do not. (The compiler could, and likely will in the future, do a better job at getting rid of some of these that don't exist after `yield` or `async` calls and therefore don't really have to be fields, but for the time being all the locals become fields).

So there are a few times when explicit locals with a single operation on them are slightly different to doing the operation directly on the means by which you obtained the value, though your example is not one of those times.